# How to create a new form and make all other forms not clickable until that form is disposed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I once read a tutorial about how to create a new form and make it above all other windows so you can click only it - like in internet explorer for example when you click on browse for a file you can't click the main window until you finish using the browse window.

Also what is the best way to get values from a form back, for exmpale on my second form I have a listbox and when a user clicks on one of the values the first form (mainform) should get the event - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to show the form as a modal dialog box. `Form.ShowDialog()` [Here you can read more about this topic.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

You can access parent form (back form) in couple ways:

- Make modal form constructor to accept parent from as parameter
- Put parent form reference into some global variable that can be accessed from modal form
- ...

To get an event from child form you can do something like this:

```
form.myListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
form.ShowDialog();
```

You need to make myListBox control public in order to access it from parent (caller) form.

Comment: thanks so much :) that worked for me. i used this a bit diffrent but that works :)

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want:

```
using (MyCustomForm form = new MyCustomForm(...))
{
    if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        // Now use the values in form
        // (e.g. through properties of the form)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not complete.. You are missing the part about getting values from parent form.

Comment: @HABJAN: The question talks about getting values from the *child* form, as far as I can tell... hence my comments. If my question isn't clear enough, hopefully the OP can provide more details about what they're trying to do.

Comment: Ah.. sorry, i misunderstand the question. My fault.

Comment: i want to get something like an event the moment the user selects one of the values in the listbox-i have a button the user has to click -should i fo this like this:  `code`((Button[])(window.Controls.Find("button1",false)))[0].Click+=new EventHandler(nameSelected);   `code`       @jon-skeet

Answer (score 3):

Just use a modal form, which is done by calling `.ShowDialog()` after you've made an instance of it.

To get the values back, just store them in properties of the form, and then read those properties from the parent window/code before it goes out of scope. You'd handle the `SelectionChanged` event in the code-behind of your new form and set a property with the value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Create your form and
In your calling code do the following:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.ShowDialog();
```

To get the values back, simply create properties on your form that map to the values of your controls (make sure you don't dispose your form before you access the properties!):

```
public class MyForm
{
//...

  public string FirstName
  {
     get
     {
         return firstNameTextBox.Text;
     }
  }
}
```

Then call the properties from your calling code after the dialog is done:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string myFirstName = form.FirstName;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: that doesnt realy help since i need the value to go as a event-the moment someone select the name.