# Loading another form on top

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Is it possible to load another form on top of one form. User should not be able to interact with first form. If user minimize the first form the stacked form should also minimized. Is this doable?

For example, User loads Form A, click some controls and Form B appears. now until Form B is closed, user should not be able to do anything in form A.

Comment: just add another form2 as `class` then you can call it from form1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a new form and make all other forms not clickable until that form is disposed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475701/how-to-create-a-new-form-and-make-all-other-forms-not-clickable-until-that-form)

Answer (score 1):

> For example, User loads Form A, click some controls and Form B
>   appears. now until Form B is closed, user should not be able to do
>   anything in form A.

This sounds like you need to show `FormB` using `ShowDialog` with `FormA` as parent.

```
FormB formb = new FormB();
formb.ShowDialog(this);//Where this is FormA
```

Comment: If I use showDialog, then I am not able to call any method of the formb.

Comment: Why can't you call `showProgress`? You should be able to do(from another thread, and by calling formb.BeginInvoke)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using MDI?

[csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-mdi-form.htm](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-mdi-form.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the base form or the first form as MDI Parent and all other forms as it's child...so you will have full contorl over the child forms like moving, closing, minimizing. It will fullfill your requirements.